# Let $m$ be a natural number with digits consisting entirely of $6'$s and $0'$s. Prove that $m$ is not the square of a natural number.

Tags: number-theory

> Question: Let $m$ be a natural number with digits consisting entirely of $6'$s and $0'$s. Prove that $m$ is not the square of a natural number.

My approach: Given that $m\in\mathbb{N}$ with digits consisting entirely of $6'$s and $0'$s. Let this property be called $P$.

Now for the sake of contradiction let us assume that $m$ is a perfect square, that is $m=k^2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Now since $m$ ends either with $6$ or $0$, implies that $m$ is even, which in turn implies that $2|m$. Therefore, $2|k^2\implies 2|k\implies k=2l$, for some $l\in\mathbb{N}$.

Thus $k^2=4l^2\implies m=4l^2\implies 4|m.$

Also observe that the sum of the digits of $m$ is equal to $6j$, for some $j\in\mathbb{Z}.$ Now since $3|6j$, implies that $3|m$. Proceeding as above we will have $9|m$.

Now since $\gcd(4,9)=1$ and $4|m, 9|m$, implies that $36|m$.

Now clearly two cases are possible:

$1.$ $m$ ends with $6$ and

$2.$ $m$ ends with $0$.

Observe that if $(1)$ holds true then $\frac{m}{6}$ ends with $1$, which implies that $\frac{m}{6}$ is odd. But $6|\frac{m}{6}\implies 2|\frac{m}{6},$ which implies that $\frac{m}{6}$ is even. Thus this case leads to a contradiction, which implies that $m$ doesn't ends with $6$. Or in other words this implies that all the natural numbers $m$ (the natural numbers having property $P$) ending with $6$ cannot be a perfect square.

Now if $(2)$ holds true, then $5|m.$ Now since $m$ is a perfect square, implies that $5^2|m$. Now since $\gcd(5^2,6^2)=1$, implies that $5^2\times 6^2|m$. Now this clearly means that $m$ ends with $00$.

How to proceed from here?

The problem can be solved by taking$\pmod {100}$ of all the natural numbers and eventually arrive at a contradiction, but that doesn't seem to be efficient enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that a natural number made entirely of 6's and 0's is not a square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335673/proving-that-a-natural-number-made-entirely-of-6s-and-0s-is-not-a-square)

Comment: In line 6, we deduce that 9 divides m; can somebody explain this to me? Because m is made up of 0 and 6, it is true that 3 divides the sum of m's digits, i.e., m. But, based on this logic, can we deduce that 9 divides m as well? Consider the numbers 60 and 606, which do not fulfil the reasoning. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here goes my solution.

Given that $m\in\mathbb{N}$ with digits consisting entirely of $6'$s and $0'$s. Let this property be called $P$.

Now for the sake of contradiction let us assume that $m$ is a perfect square, that is $m=k^2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Now since $m$ ends either with $6$ or $0$, implies that $m$ is even, which in turn implies that $2|m$. Therefore, $2|k^2\implies 2|k\implies k=2l$, for some $l\in\mathbb{N}$.

Thus $k^2=4l^2\implies m=4l^2\implies 4|m.$

Also observe that the sum of the digits of $m$ is equal to $6j$, for some $j\in\mathbb{Z}.$ Now since $3|6j$, implies that $3|m$. Proceeding as above we will have $9|m$.

Now since $\gcd(4,9)=1$ and $4|m, 9|m$, implies that $36|m$.

Now clearly two cases are possible:

$1.$ $m$ ends with $6$ and

$2.$ $m$ ends with $0$.

Observe that if $(1)$ holds true then $\frac{m}{6}$ ends with $1$, which implies that $\frac{m}{6}$ is odd. But $6|\frac{m}{6}\implies 2|\frac{m}{6},$ which implies that $\frac{m}{6}$ is even. Thus this case leads to a contradiction, which implies that $m$ doesn't ends with $6$.

Now if $(2)$ holds true, then $5|m.$ Now since $m$ is a perfect square, implies that $5^2|m$. Now since $\gcd(5^2,36)=1$, implies that $5^2\times 6^2|m$. Thus $100|m$, which clearly means that $m$ ends with $00$. Now this also implies that $m'=\frac{m}{100}$ is yet again a perfect square ($\because$ $100=10^2$ is a perfect square) consisting entirely  of digits $6'$s and $0'$s. Then we can yet again conclude that $100|m'$ and $m'$ ends with $00$. Now let $m''=\frac{m'}{100}$ and keep continuing this iteration. After this iteration ends we can certainly conclude that $m=100^j$ for some $j\in\mathbb{N}$. This also implies that $m$ is entirely a combination of $1$ and $2j$ $0'$s, which contradicts the fact that $m$ has property $P$. Hence $m$ does not end with $0$.

Thus $m$ does not end neither with $0$ nor with $6$, which is a clear contradiction to the property $P$.

Hence $m$ is not the square of a natural number.

Comment: This is what the first answer by TonyK said already, so you really should give credit to that.

Answer (score 2):

If $m$ ends with $00$, you can simply start again with $m'=m/100$.

And if $m$ ends in $60$, then $5|m$, therefore $25|m$; but multiples of $25$ must end in $00,25,50,$ or $75$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @TonyK establishes that $m$ cannot end in a string of one or more $0$s, so it must end in $06$ or $66$. Hence, $m=100k+6$ or $m=100k+66$. Since $m$ is even, its square must be evenly divisible by $4$. But $(100k+6,\ 100k+66)\equiv 2 \bmod 4$, so a contradiction results, and the hypothesis that $m$ can be a square composed entirely of the digits $0,6$ must be false.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it for 2).

Let $N = N'\times 10^k$ so that $N$ ends with $k$ zeros but once you remove the $k$ zeros $N'$ will end with $6$.

If $N=m^2$ is a perfect square then $k$ is an even number of zeros and $m^2 = N'\times 10^k$ and $m = \sqrt {N'}\times 10^{\frac k2}$ and $N'$ is a perfect square that ends in $6$ and which contains only sixes and zeros.

......And you are back to case 1).

.....

Or if you grab the tiger from the *other* end (the one without the point teeth) and say

$n$ is a number that ends with $k$ zeros ($k$ could be zero and $n$ could and with no zeros).  Then $n = m\times 10^k$ where $m$ is a number that does not equal $0$.

Then $m = 10a + b$ where $b = 1,....,9$ and

$n = (10a + b)\times 10^k$.

And $n^2 = (100a^2 + 20ab + b^2)\times 10^{2k}$.

Now suppose $n^2$ has only $0$s and $6$s.  Then $100a^2 + 20ab + b^2$ has only $0$s and $6$es.

So $b^2$ must end in a six or zero but of $1^2, 2^2, 3^3....., 9^2$ only $4$ and $6$ will end in a $6$ and none of them end in a $0$.  So $b = 4$ or $b = 6$.

If $b = 4$ then $100a^2 + 80a + 16$ contains only zeros and sixes.  So $80a + 16$ must end with either $06$ or $66$.  Which means $8a$ must end in either $9$ or $5$. But that's impossible as $8a$ is even.

If $b = 6$ then $100a^2 + 120a + 36$ contains only zeros and sixes.  So $120a+36$ must end with either $06$ or $66$.  Which means $12a$ must end in either $7$ or $3$.  But that's impossible as $12a$ is even.

So it is impossible for $n^2$ to have only sixes and zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which I think is simpler is to use the following fact:

> If $m$ is a perfect square, then for every prime $p$ the power of $p$ occurring in $m$ - that is, the largest $s$ such that $p^s\vert m$ - must be even.

To see how this is relevant, first consider ${m\over 2}$. This has only $3$s and $0$s as digits. In particular, we have ${m\over 2}=10^k\cdot c$ for some $k$ and some $c$ which is not divisible by either $2$ or $5$ (since $c$ ends in "$3$").

But then we have $$m=2\cdot 10^k\cdot c=2^{\color{red}{k+1}}5^kc$$ for some $k$ and some $c$ not divisible by either $2$ or $5$, and this is impossible: if $k$ is odd then $m$ can't be a square since the power of $5$ occurring in $m$ is odd, and if $k$ is even then $m$ can't be a square since the power of $2$ occurring in $m$ is odd.

---

A bit more snappily: let $Pow_a(b)$ be the largest $n$ such that $a^n\vert b$. Then if $m$ consists only of $6$s and $0$s, we have $Pow_2(m)=Pow_5(m)+1$. This means that one of $Pow_2(m)$ and $Pow_5(m)$ is odd. But if $m$ were a perfect square then $Pow_p(m)$ would be even for every prime $p$.

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach
Any number is of the form $10^n a$  where n is a whole number so if we square it we get $10^{2n} a^2$ basically if we remove the trailing zeroes the resulting number must also be a square.
Incase of m it looks like
m=6.....6
or
$m=6(1.....1)=2*3(1....1)$ and we notice that the resulting number is odd  but for m to be square we needed at least another two.
Therefore m is not perfect square